# What's meaning of Cheap thrills?

Tags: meaning

A song "cheap thrills", what's meaning of it?

Comment: Something that is fun and exciting as you do it, and doesn't require much engagement, but afterwards you do not feel proud of yourself. Or, something that is fun and exciting, but only for unsophisticated people. Usually not expensive. Something like a cock fight or a strip show might be called that.

Comment: Looks like Cheap thrills goes back to the early 1890's. Further than I thought: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cheap%20thrills%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1890,cd_max:1897&lr=lang_en  That's 80 years before Janis Joplin gets her hold on it. Meaning seems to vary some, but is usually connected with nonintellectual sensationalism. Usage climbed quickly in the 1970s: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cheap+thrills&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccheap%20thrills%3B%2Cc0